# How to add text at bottom in splash screen using Flutter_native_splash

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to FLutter. how to add text at bottom in splash screen using Flutter_native_splash ? is there a way?

this this my code:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  background_image: "assets/splashscreen_background.png"
  image: assets/images/logo-text.png
```

Answer (score 1):

the owner said: [link](https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/363#issuecomment-1137460674)

> There is not a way to add dynamic text. If you want static text, you
> can add it to the splash image.

another workaroud is, make your custom splash screen with statefull/stateless widget.
In common case, if you only use custom widget as a splash screen, there will be a white screen before the flutter initiated. Therefore better use native splash to avoid that.

after the flutter has initiated, remove the native splash and display your custom splash widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could add text as an image with the package's `branding` option.